# Validating auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to the change fuction to validate my auto complete text box

So far my auto complete works with this following code:

Autocomplete code:

```
$("#Form_Ser_Num").autocomplete({
        source: "@Url.Action("SerialProdNumStockSiteAutoComplete", "Ajax")?stocksitenum=LW&model=" + $("#Form_Prod_Num").val(),

        minlength: 2,
        delay: 300,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.target.innerText = ui.item.label.split(',')[0];
            $("#Form_Ser_Num_Source").val(ui.item.label.split(',')[1]);
        }
    });
```

I want to add this so it validates:

```
change: function( event, ui ) {
    if ( !ui.item ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i" ), valid = false;

        select.children("option").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (!valid) {
            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
            $(this).val("");
            select.val("");
            input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have found this online, but i cant implement it to my code.

Any ideas how i can use this change function to my auto complete function.

Comment: what is your data, and what the validation actually for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to check/validate your text field value with the source, here is something that you can give it a try. Just modify the change and reponse functions as follows:

```
change:function(event, ui){
  if (!ui.item){
    $(this).val('');
    }
  }

response: function(e, ui) {
  if (ui.content.length == 0) {
    $(this).val("");
  }
}
```